# Error importing tensorflow module

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use the command import tensorflow as tf I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rodri647\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\chemvae\lib\sit
e-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_im
port_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\rodri647\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\chemvae\lib\imp
ortlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rodri647\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\chemvae\lib\sit
e-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\rodri647\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\chemvae\lib\sit
e-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module
>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\rodri647\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\chemvae\lib\sit
e-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_im
port_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\rodri647\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\chemvae\lib\imp
ortlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

I'm using tensorflow gpu 1.1.0 on python 3.5. The code I'm trying to compile is here:  https://github.com/aspuru-guzik-group/chemical_vae

Comment: As a workaround you can install Tensorflow 1.5. I am trying to implement concrete solution if possible, and post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have no installed `MSVCP140.DLL` in your system. You can try installing [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587), uninstall then install TF again.

If it doesn't work, try to [download](https://www.dll-files.com/msvcp140.dll.html) and import this dll directly as it [explained here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8385#issuecomment-286643334)